# Finding the endpoint of a named bone in Irrlicht

Tags: models, irrlicht, skeletal-animation

I'm making a tank game that will have multiple tanks.  I want to be able to define the weapon placements using bones that I can add right inside the modelling program (Blender to be exact).

All tanks will have a bone called Body and a bone called Turret, and then names like Cannon0 and PickupGun for where the shots will be fired from that are attached to the Turret bone.  Is there some way to find the absolute end position of a bone that I choose by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I'm using IrrlichtLime and I do this:

```
AnimatedMeshNode.GetJointNode("muzzle").RelativeTransformation
```

to get the transformation relative to the model origin.